# Observable.interval() with initialDelay

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a polling service which is implemented using `Observable.interval(POLL_INTERVAL, Seconds)`. This works fine but I would like the first delay to be 0, I mean I would like to start the poll immediately and then continue to poll every POLL_INTERVAL. How is this  achievable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RxJava has 3 timing related operators (+1 overload each):

- `timer(long delay, TimeUnit unit [, Scheduler scheduler])` emits a single 0L after the delay,
- `timer(long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit [, Scheduler scheduler])` emits a 0L after the initial delay and ever incrementing values periodically after that,
- `interval(long interval, TimeUnit unit [, Scheduler scheduler])` emits 0L after the interval and 1L, 2L, etc. periodically. It is equivalent to `timer(interval, interval, unit)`.

Comment: Awesome, so this means I could replace `Observable.interval(POLL_INTERVAL, Seconds)` with `Observable.timer(0, POLL_INTERVAL, Seconds)` and achieve what I wanted right?

Comment: Looks like `timer(long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler)` has been deprecated.
Interval now supports initialDelay `interval(long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler)`